"Error HH604: Troubleshooting 'missing trie node' issue when forking BSC mainnet using Hardhat
I encountered an issue while attempting to fork the Binance Smart Chain (BSC) mainnet using Hardhat. Here's the command I used:
npx hardhat node --fork https://bsc-dataseed1.defibit.io/
However, I received the following error message:
Error HH604: Error running JSON-RPC server: The response reported error -32000: missing trie node. (optional data: None)

Received the exact same error when forking binance blockchain.   I was using https://bsc-dataseed.binance.org. It seemed to be associated with the hardhat version that I was using: v2.22.3 produced this error while rolling back to v2.17.1 eliminated the error from happening.
Ran this command:
npx hardhat node
which picked up the binance blockchain in my hardhat.config.ts file:
const config: HardhatUserConfig = {
solidity: {
compilers: [{ version: "0.8.10" }, { version: "0.8.13" }],
},
networks: {
hardhat: {
forking: {
url: binance_provider_url,   <-- Set to https://bsc-dataseed.binance.org
},
},
Got this error:
Error HH604: Error running JSON-RPC server: The response reported error `-32000`: `missing trie node`. (optional data: None). Request: [{"id":4,"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_getBalance","params":["0x3c44cdddb6a900fa2b585dd299e03d12fa4293bc","0x244e3bd"]},{"id":5,"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_getTransactionCount","params":["0x3c44cdddb6a900fa2b585dd299e03d12fa4293bc","0x244e3bd"]},{"id":6,"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_getCode","params":["0x3c44cdddb6a900fa2b585dd299e03d12fa4293bc","0x244e3bd"]}] 

